# Select an Image from Resources on user input to set the Image of a PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, winforms, for-loop, embedded-resource

This probably doesn't make a lot of sense, but I'm trying to change the image of a PictureBox to a users request if a user has searched for it and it matches one in a current string.

I keep receiving a `"System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'"` when I run it.

Each string in the array matches the name of an Image in the Project's Resources.

```
string[] TShirts = new string[] { "New York", "Melbourne", "London", "Sydney", "Los Angeles" };

for (int i = 0; i < TShirts.Length; i++ )
{
    if (txtSearch.Text == TShirts[i])
    {
        string x = TShirts[i];
       ptbItem.Image = new Bitmap(x); // error occurs here (this is what I can't work out)
    }
}
```

Comment: x must be a filename, and i  dont see that in your code, x= name of town..see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-bitmap-ctor(system-string)

Comment: @Frenchy Thank you! I've been reading through it a bit, but I don't quite understand how to make x equal to a filename. Could you help me further? Thanks

Comment: in your case , i suppose you have resources in your program..so you have to use resourcemanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager) to access resources by name at run-time.
You can pass a string to its [GetObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject) method and cast to the resource Type.

For example:

```
int idx = Array.IndexOf(TShirts, txtSearch.Text);

if (idx >= 0) {
    ptbItem.Image?.Dispose();
    ptbItem.Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(TShirts[idx]);
}
```

---

Since you have a collection of strings, you could fill a ComboBox instead of using a TextBox as input, so your Users don't need to *guess* a name and avoid type mistakes.